# What will be the runtime signature?

Tags: java, reflection, type-erasure

I have a bit of a problem understanding Java's type erasure when it comes to bounded types. Consider this:

```
class Event {} // From the API
class FooEvent extends Event {}

abstract class Foo<EventType extends Event> {
    public abstract <E extends EventType> void onEventCaught(E event);
}

class Bar extends Foo<FooEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onEventCaught(FooEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Apparently this compiles without problems. The question that I ask myself is, for which parameter-types is `Bar#onEventCaught()` declared, here (as in, what does reflection think)?

Is it `onEventCaught(FooEvent event)` or maybe `onEventCaught(Event event)`?

Comment: Don't name your generic types like classes you already have. For instance you can create class like `class Foo<String>` but for this class `String` will represent generic type, not `java.lang.String` type, so you will not be able to use `String s = "hello world"` inside it. Name generic types simpler like `class Foo<T>`.

Comment: @Pshemo Noted, I guess that would avoid some confusion on my side in the future...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

You have

```
<EventType extends Event>
```

and

```
<E extends EventType>
```

The leftmost bound of `E` is `EventType`, which is another type variable, whose leftmost bound is `Event`. So the erasure of `E` in

```
public abstract <E extends EventType> void onEventCaught(E event);
```

is `Event`.

Type variables do appear in `.class` files, and you can use them in reflection.

```
Class<?> clazz = Foo.class;
TypeVariable typeVariable = clazz.getTypeParameters()[0];
Type type = typeVariable.getBounds()[0];

System.out.println(typeVariable);
System.out.println(type);
```

prints

```
EventType
class com.example.Event
```

Comment: So when the method is annotated with, let's say `@interface Subscribe` and someone scans the class via reflection for methods with `Subscribe` they will see a method `onEventCaught(Event event)`, is that correct?

Comment: @WorldSEnder It depends what they use. If they use `Method#getParameterTypes` they will see `Event`. If they use `Method#getParameters` which returns a `Parameter[]`, they will see `E`. Though you can always find what the `E` is with some reverse engineering on the method's type variables or class.

Comment: What I thought about: When the method is annotated in `Bar` only, does the annotation still get applied to `onEventCaught(Event event)`? `Bar` doesn't use generics in its declaration of `onEventCaught(FooEvent ev)` so how would that work out? I would be happy if you could quote the standard for this, too.

Comment: @WorldSEnder In the same JLS section _The erasure of every other type is the type itself_. So for `Bar#onEventCaught(FooEvent)`, the parameter type will be `FooEvent`.